# How to create a compute instance with a larger disk from a smaller snapshot?

Tags: python, shell, google-compute-engine

When creating a GCE instance, I'd like to have a persistent root partition that's 20GB, but with the filesystem cloned from a snapshot that's only 10GB. That is, I'd like an extra 10GB of free space to play with.

Is there a way to accomplish this automatically with the GCE python libraries or maybe some startup shell scripts (https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript)?

Answer (score 1):

I was also looking for this and found the answer at the [official documentation page](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#restoresnapshotlargersize). I think it is best to create a persistent disk like that and then creating a snapshot and using that when creating your new 20GB instances.

Comment: In particular, the --size_gb flag is how you'd access this via gcutil.  From the python API, you'd set the 'sizeGb' JSON field in addition to 'sourceImage' or 'sourceSnapshot'.

See: https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/disks/insert

Answer (score 0):

While not automatic with a GCE start-up script, you can do it manually.

When creating boot disks larger than the default of 10GB, here's how you can gain all of your disk space:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sda
# Press the following keyboard commands...
# c [enter]
# u [enter]
# p [enter]
# note the "Id" number, often "83"
# d [enter]
# n [enter]
# p [enter]
# 1 [enter]
# [enter] for default of 2048
# [enter] for default of end of disk
# p [enter] and confirm that the "Id" is the same as it was earlier, often "83"
# w [enter]
sudo reboot
```

Log back in, and then...

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/sda1
```

Run `df -hT` before and after to see the applied difference.